# No output from C program

Tags: c

I wrote this code in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int vector1[50000];
    int  n, m, c, i, j;
    int size = 50000;
    int aux;
    clock_t starttime, finaltime;
    long double elapsedtime;
    for (m = 1; m <= 10000; m++){
        starttime = clock();
        for (c = 0; c <= 49999; c++) {
            vector1[c] = rand() % 5000001;
        }
        for(i= size -1; i >= 1; i--) {
            for(j=0; j<i ; j++) {
                if(vector1[j]>vector1[j+1]) {
                    aux = vetor1[j];
                    vector1[j] = vector1[j+1];
                    vector1[j+1] = aux;

                }
            }
        }
        finaltime = clock();

        tempoGasto = (finaltime-starttime);
        printf("time in seconds: %Lf \n", elapsedtime);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and, when compiled, the window of code:blocks shows nothing

Note: I'm using windows 7.
the code is supposed to sort a vector of 50000 slots filled up with random integers 10000 times and shows the time elapsed as the program runs at each time

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem ?

Comment: add `getChar()` before return 0.

Comment: And learn to format your code. After you do many problems are going to be solved by themselves.

Comment: @Ajean really ? I just made an Edit on it. Why did you corrected that. Your edit looks terrible.

Comment: What is your question? I don't see a question.

Comment: "when compiled, the window of code:blocks shows nothing": do you mean when the program is *run*?  Else, what do you expect to see?

Comment: You probably aren't seeing any output because of the nested loop that has to iterate about a billion times before you reach the `printf()` statement. If you optimize the program to run as fast as possible (try adding `-O3` to the compiler options), then it might be a bit more responsive. Otherwise, try writing more efficient code.

Comment: I compiled the code on my machine and everything works fine. It shows me 'Tempo em segundos' and a value. After some time, as @squeamishossifrage pointed, efficiency should be the problem here. It's taking too long for your program to see something. Just try to wait. And try to code in english, not in portuguese.

Comment: thank you all for commenting. i meant "run", i'll write the code in english next time.

Comment: @John Bollingeri expected to see a vector with 50000 random values ordered by bubble sort.

Comment: @user1 where exactly do i write "getchar()"?

Comment: Debugger.........................DCV

Comment: @Michi Any edit you did is not showing up in the revision history, so probably we were just editing at the same time without realizing, and yours became invalid because I happened to post it first.

Comment: Is your question, "How do you debug C code?"

Comment: @david schwartz My is question is: is there any logical/syntax error? or is just a unefficiency problem?. I'm receiving a blank window as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code invokes *undefined behaviour* . See here -

```
  for (c = 1; c <= 50000; c++) {
        vetor1[c] = rand() % 5000000 + 1;
    }
```

This will also access index `50000` of array `vector1` but you don't have index `50000` , as you have declared it like this -

```
int vetor1[50000];
```

You have index from `0 to 49999` . So first change this condition .